# Change background color after add an item to a list with Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a table where new items will be showed with a different background color. The exemple bellow shows what I'm doing.

```js
var data = [{
  name: "Gibson",
  id: "1"
}, {
  name: "Fender",
  id: "2"
}, {
  name: "Godin",
  id: "3"
}, {
  name: "Tagima",
  id: "4"
}, {
  name: "Giannini",
  id: "5"
}];

var list = [{
  name: "Gibson",
  id: "1"
}, {
  name: "Fender",
  id: "2"
}];

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.mylist = ko.mapping.fromJS(list);
  self.data = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
  self.selectedItem = ko.observable(undefined);

  self.addItem = function() {
    if (self.selectedItem == undefined) return;
    self.mylist.push(self.selectedItem());
    $("#" + self.selectedItem().id()).addClass("newItem");
    self.selectedItem(undefined);
  }
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
.newItem {
  background-color: #DCEDC1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: $root.data, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption: 'Select yout Guitar', value: selectedItem, event:{change: $root.addItem}"></select>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <p>
          Guitars
        </p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:mylist">
    <tr data-bind="attr:{id: $data.id}">
      <td>
        <p data-bind="text: $data.name"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But in in some views, the new row in the table is added after the function addItem finish so the background color do not change. Is there another way to do it or to workaround this issue?

Comment: When you add a new element dynamically, you need to select that element from any parent which was there on loading . use   `$("table #" + self.selectedItem().id()).addClass("newItem")`. BTW knockout has `css` binding that you can use to add that class to your desired element

Comment: @Matt.kaaj it didn't work. The case is, sometimes when I call the addClass function of the element, it has not beed created.

Comment: use knockout `css` binding then once you are sure the element has been created and bound by knockout then that `class` gets effect . http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

Comment: @Matt.kaaj how could I use css binding inside a foreach and only for new elements of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a duplicate item with the same `id` then in order to add a class `jquery` will select the first element with that id from DOM tree (id is a unique selector).
 Here is what you can do by using `knockout`
Example :https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/213/

HTML :

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.data, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption: 'Select yout Guitar', value: selectedItem, event:{change: $root.addItem}"></select>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <p>
          Guitars
        </p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:mylist">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p data-bind="text:name, css:CSS"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

VM:

```
var data = [{name: "Gibson",id: "1"}, {name: "Fender",id: "2"},
                         {name: "Godin",id: "3"},{name: "Tagima",id: "4"},
             {name: "Giannini",id: "5"}];
var list = [{name: "Gibson",id: "1"}, {name: "Fender",id: "2"}];

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
   self.mylist = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.data = ko.observableArray([]);

   self.mylist($.map(list, function (element) {
        return new ItemViewModel(element);
      }));

        self.data($.map(data, function (element) {
        return new DataViewModel(element);
      }));
  self.selectedItem = ko.observable(undefined);

  self.addItem = function() {
    if (self.selectedItem == undefined) return;
    //uncomment below if you want only last added item has that class
       //ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.mylist(), function (item) {
       // if (item) {
       //  item.CSS('');
       // }
       //});
    self.mylist.push(new ItemViewModel({name:self.selectedItem().name() , id:self.selectedItem().id() , css:'newItem'}));
    self.selectedItem(undefined);
  }
}
var ItemViewModel = function (data){
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
  self.CSS = ko.observable(data.css ? data.css :'');
}
var DataViewModel = function (data){
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
}
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: That is a great solution but I can't change de viewModel because it is created in the server side and sent to client side using ajax.

Comment: Knockout viewModel is on client side and has nothing to do with server side . You get data using `Ajax` and then populate your data using Knockout VM on browser side . If you would like to stick to your code  instead of using `id` you need to use `class` if you have a duplicate item with the same id

Comment: I thought when you sent the data back to server side with different property the asp.net would understand it as a different class, but it would not. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery to keep track of the classes will be difficult if you're also using knockout. If your *guitar* objects remain as simple as they are, you can implement your feature with very little code (you don't have to create new viewmodels if you don't want to). This is what you'll need to do:

1. Keep track of all the new items in an array
2. For each item, determine if they need the `.isNew` class by checking if they're in this array
3. Toggle a class using the `css` binding

**Step 1:**

Inside `ViewModel` you can create a third `observableArray`. `myList` still stores all selected items, the new array `newItems` stores just the `id` properties of the items added through the UI.

**Step 2:**

In the `addItem` method, instead of selecting an element via jQuery and adding a class, we push the new item to the `newItems` array.

**Step 3:**

Replace the `attr` binding with the `css` binding that creates a computed boolean to indicate if the row is new or not:

```
<tr data-bind="css:{'newItem' : guitarIsInArray($data, $parent.newItems())}">
```

**Additional notes:**

- You were using `selectedValue` to store the `<select>` element's changes: it's better to subscribe to this value's changes than to create *another* event listener via `event: { change: fn }`
- Since your guitars are just plain objects, the *Gibson* in the `data` array will not equal the *Gibson* in `myList`. I've created a helper method to make sure you don't get duplicate values (`guitarIsInArray`).
- Eventually, even if you're not creating a `Guitar` viewmodel, I'd try to make sure there's only one object reference per guitar in your code.

Here's an updated example:

```js
var data = [{
  name: "Gibson",
  id: "1"
}, {
  name: "Fender",
  id: "2"
}, {
  name: "Godin",
  id: "3"
}, {
  name: "Tagima",
  id: "4"
}, {
  name: "Giannini",
  id: "5"
}];

var list = [{
  name: "Gibson",
  id: "1"
}, {
  name: "Fender",
  id: "2"
}];



var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.data = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
  self.mylist = ko.mapping.fromJS(list);

  self.newItems = ko.observableArray([]);

  // This excludes any guitar in mylist from data
  self.unusedData = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.data().filter(function(guitar) {
      return !guitarIsInArray(guitar, self.mylist());
    });
  });

  self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

  // Called whenever your select changes
  self.selectedItem.subscribe(function(newItem) {
    if (!newItem || guitarIsInArray(newItem, self.mylist())) {
      return;
    }

    self.mylist.push(newItem);
    self.newItems.push(newItem);
  });
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

function guitarIsInArray(guitar, array) {
  for (var g = 0; g < array.length; g += 1) {
    if (array[g].id() === guitar.id()) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
};
```

```css
.newItem {
  background-color: #DCEDC1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: $root.unusedData, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption: 'Select your Guitar', value: selectedItem"></select>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <p>
          Guitars
        </p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:mylist">
    <tr data-bind="css:{'newItem' : guitarIsInArray($data, $parent.newItems())}">
      <td>
        <p data-bind="text: $data.name"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I was thinking to do that but, as I said, my  form sometimes have a lot of lists and I will need to create and maintain a lot of other lists. After the last comment of @Matt.kaaj I just created a property "css" in the guitar viewmodel and a css bind in the table row and it worked as well. Thanks for the help.